# Echo Datetime from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a field in my database of the type datetime that gets populated using `CURRENT_TIME` when a record is inserted.
it looks like : `2015-01-05 19:07:03`

My question is how do I take this when querying the database and format it to a string so I can echo it via php.

my current code:

```
$testssql="SELECT * FROM LogTest WHERE DriverID = '$userid' AND Complete = '1'";
$testsresult=mysqli_query($conn, $testssql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($testsresult))
    {
        date('l, F d, Y', strtotime($row['Date']));
    }
```

However this doesnt work neither does just `$row['Date']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['Date']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // Change format as needed
```

**EDIT:**

You should be able to track down the error using a try/catch block:

```
try {
    $date = new DateTime($row['Date']);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // Change format as needed
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object`

Comment: No need to use createFromFormat(I) here. DateTime handles that format natively.

Comment: In your loop, if you echo $row['Date'] does any data display? Does it contain a value?

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the tip! I've updated my answer to skip that step.